# Ruby UDP Communication between two instances on local Machine

Tags: ruby, networking, udp

For testing purposes i'd like to establish a connection between two Ruby instances on localhost by using Udp on two different Ports, where both instances could send and receive to each other.

**Instance 1** has being set up in this way:

```
@to_machconn = UDPSocket.new
@to_machconn.connect("localhost", 9092) 
@from_machconn = UDPSocket.new
@from_machconn.connect("localhost", 9093)
```

**Instance 2:**

````
@from_mach = UDPSocket.new
@from_mach.bind("localhost", 9092)
@to_mach = UDPSocket.new
@to_mach.bind("localhost", 9093)```
````

Communication between Instance 1 (Sender) to Instance 2 (Receiver) works without problems  by using

**Instance 1**

```
@to_machconn.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9092)
```

**Instance 2**

```
begin
data=@from_mach.recvfrom_nonblock(512)
rescue
end
```

but the other way around by using

**Instance 2**

```
@to_mach.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9093)
```

**Instance 1**

```
begin # emulate blocking recvfrom
data=@from_machconn.recvfrom_nonblock(65)  
  rescue
    IO::WaitReadable
  IO.select([@from_machconn])
  retry
end
```

won't work, after ctrl+c on **Instance 1** will produce a

```
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:1272:in `__recvfrom_nonblock': Resource temporarily unavailable - recvfrom(2) would block (IO::EAGAINWaitReadable)
```

tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 9092 gives me

```
IP 127.0.0.1.57895 > 127.0.0.1.9092: UDP, length 265
```

tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 9093

```
IP 127.0.0.1.9093 > 127.0.0.1.9093: UDP, length 65
```

Communication between two instances with only one socket involved won´t work either, the result will be the same.

My theory is that sending to 9093 from instance 2 causes somewhat like a loop, where the message which has been delivered by Instance 2 is immediate catched again by Instance 2, so it won't get "through" to Instance 1, but if so, why?

Probably Binding? If yes, how should especially the Receive-Command on instance 1 be formed? Or has both sides once to used "bind" and "connect" for each port (on the other instance the other way around)?

I'm no Network expert - unfortunaly..

Comment: `@to_mach.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9093)` - there is no `to_mach` at instance 2. Did you mean `to_machconn`? Also note that it makes no sense to a) connect a UDP socket  to a specific peer and b) also give the peer inside `send`. The latter destination will likely be ignored and the data get send to the connected peer instead.

Comment: You're right, i have corrected the Post, it was the other way around.

Comment: The socket receiving the data is the socket which got bound to the address, not the one who connected to the address. Thus `@to_mach.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9093)` send the data to `to_mach` itself, not to `from_machconn`.

Comment: Thanks,  yep, i've resolved the isuss. See my next post :)

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully i solved the issue.

Instance 1 (sending and receiving as usual):

```
@to_machconn = UDPSocket.new
  
@from_machconn = UDPSocket.new
@from_machconn.bind("localhost", 9093) 

Receiving from Instance 2:
get=@from_machconn.recvfrom(65)  

Sending to Instance 2:
@to_machconn.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9092)
```

Instance 2:

```
@from_mach = UDPSocket.new
@from_mach.bind("localhost", 9092)

@to_mach = UDPSocket.new

Receiving from Instance 1:
data=@from_mach.recvfrom_nonblock(512)


Sending to instance 1:
@to_mach.send(data,0,"127.0.0.1",9093)
Receiving from Instance 1
```

My fault: I throught that at least a "connect" or "bind" to a socket should be mandatory on those Ports, which are now excluded from "connect" and "bind". Thanks!